# I succeeded in getting 2D array elemnts from user but I failed of printing it

Tags: java

How can I print this array in 2D as every time I run the program, 
the dimension of the output array is 1D.?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i; int y = 0;
    Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("plz enter rows nom ");
    int j=s.nextInt();  
    System.out.println("plz enter column nom");
    int g=s.nextInt();
    int a[][]=new int [j][g];
    for (  i=0;i<j;i++){
        System.out.println("plz full the elemnts of " + (i+1) + "  row ");
        for ( y=0;y<g;y++){
            System.out.println("plz enter the elemnt of " + (y+1) +"  column " );
            a[i][y]=s.nextInt();
        }

    }    System.out.println(a[i][y]);
}
```

Comment: What does it mean `dimension of the output array as 1D`?

Comment: I mean that the output should be like that 
{5 , 6 , 4 };
{5 ,85 ,45 }
but the output is {5,6,4,5,85,45} ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Arrays.deepToString(array);`.

If you're looking for something a little more "2D", then you can do this (which also works for a ragged array):

```
for (x=0;x<a.length;x++){
    for (y=0;y<a[x].length;y++){
        System.out.printf("%d ",a[x][y]);
    }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: could you tell me how ?

Comment: @Abdalla call it like `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));`, or just copy/paste the other option. From your comment, it looks like you want the first one.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaks alot ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can print your array like this to get 2D form :

```
for (  i=0;i<j;i++){
    for ( y=0;y<g;y++){
        System.out.print(a[i][y] + " |" );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```